# SQL запрос

Tags: sqlite, sql

Добрый вечер. Помогите, пожалуйста, с составлением запроса. Буду очень благодарен.

```
SELECT one.name, (SUM(one.summ)+SUM(two.summ)) FROM table1 one JOIN table2 two ON (one.name = two.name)
```

Мне необходимо создать представление, которое будет содержать в себе Имя (Name) и Сумму (Summ) из 2-х (вообще-то 3-х, но неважно) других таблиц. Проблема в том, чтобы получить множество записей типа Name Summ. 
Надеюсь, понятно объяснил. То есть имеется:

```
Table1 
Name      Summ
Ваня      100
Петя      200
Коля      150
Саша      30
Никита    300

Table1 
Name      Summ
Ваня      40
Петя      10
Коля      50

Нужно получить на выходе
Table3 
Name      Summ
Ваня      140
Петя      210
Коля      200
Саша      30
Никита    300
```

Я пробовал добавить в конец запроса выборку имён. Но в результате получал только 1 строку.

```
 SELECT one.name, (SUM(one.summ)+SUM(two.summ)) FROM table1 one JOIN table2 two ON (one.name = two.name) WHERE one.name = (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table1)
```

Подскажите, что исправить или добавить. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT one.name ,sum(one.summ +two.summ)  
FROM one JOIN two ON one.name = two.name  
GROUP BY one.name
```

Проверил у себя в sqlserver, запрос работает. Как сделать из запроса представление, думаю, знаете?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.Всё работает.Проверил и с 3я таблицами:-).  Надо будет почитать подробнее про GROUP BY. Спасибо ещё раз большое.

Comment: Пожалуйста :)

Comment: Ваш запрос отработает неправильно  Если в таблице1 к примеру есть Петя, а в Таблице2 Пети нету, и наоборот. Проверял на MySQL

Comment: @Ale_x. Мой ответ был дан согласно задаче, посмотрите на условие. В первой таблице содержатся все имена, поэтому все будет правильно работать. Distinct согласен, здесь не нужен, но я привык его вставлять, чтобы не было повторений.

Comment: @Andy92, Странно, что у вас даст результатом, как в примере "Нужно получить на выходе Table3 ".  Проверьте еще раз. В вашем запросе в результат попадут только те строки, мена которых присутствуют в табл1 и табл2.
К тому же MSSQL такой запрос вообще не выполнит Column 'table1.summ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.: SELECT table1.name ,(table1.summ+table2.summ) as summ FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name GROUP BY table1.name см тут http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c18c8/3

Answer (score 1):

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT name, sum(summ) as summ
FROM
( 
  SELECT  name, sum(summ) as summ
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY name
UNION ALL
  SELECT  name, sum(summ) as summ
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY name
// и т.д сколько у вас таблиц
) as tsumm
GROUP BY name
```

Но дело в том, что при разрастании таблиц, записей на запросы много времени будет уходить.

Еще такой вопрос: почему у вас в архитектуре в разных таблицах хранятся одинаковые сущности - Имя - сумма?
Из тех данных, что есть, можно сделать вывод о неправильной архитектуре БД.